# When does removing k edges going into every vertex keeps the graph strongly connected?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (N,E)$ be a graph where $N$ is the set of nodes and $E$ is the set of edges.

- Let $e_{ij} \in E$ be an edge from node $j\in N$ to node $i\in N$.
- Let $E_{i} = \{ e_{ik}\in E \}$ be the set of all edges going into node $i$. Note that we can write $E = \cup_{i\in N}E_{i}$.
- Let $\mathcal{E}_i(k) = \{ S \subset E_i \ | \ |S| = |E_{i}| - k\}$. This is a set where each element is $E_i$ with $k$ elements removed. So for example if $E_1 = \{e_{12}, e_{13}, e_{14}\}$ then $\mathcal{E}_1(1) = \{\{e_{12}, e_{13}\}, \{e_{12}, e_{14}\}, \{e_{13}, e_{14}\}\}$.
- Let $\mathcal{E}(k) = \{ \cup_{i\in N} \tilde{E}_{i} \ |\ \tilde{E}_{i}\in \mathcal{E}_{i}(k) \}$. This is set $E$ but with each node $i$ removing $k$ edges going into node $i$.

Question: Given a $k$ and a strongly connected graph $G =(N,E)$ where if $e_{ij}\in E$ then $e_{ji}\in E$, under what conditions of the original graph $G$, is the graph $\hat{G} = (N, \hat{E})$ strongly connected for any $\hat{E}\in \mathcal{E}(k)$?

I don't really have a clue where to start with this. I'm not even sure what resources can help me with this problem either.

Comment: I haven't done the problem, but the first thing I notice is that  the in-degree of every node is equal to the out-degree, so the graph has an Euler cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $k=1$ choose a node $i$ and remove the edge $e_{ji}\in E$ for all $j\in N$. Then there is no outgoing edge from node $i$ and therefore the graph is not strongly connected.